# Roblox, Tool won't animate when equipped?

Tags: lua, game-development, roblox

[The Tool Location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsn4M.png)

```
local character = player.Character
local animation = 
script:FindFirstChild("Equip")
local equipAnimTrack =character.Humanoid:LoadAnimation(animation)
local tool = script.Parent


tool.Equipped:Connect(function()

    equipAnimTrack:Play()
end)
```

Whenever I run the Game, I get the error "Players.dradsds.Backpack.Tool.Script:2: attempt to index nil with 'Character'"
I already tried changing the character variable to workspace:WaitForChild(player.Name) which then gets an error which indexes nil for Name.

```
  Players.dradsds.Backpack.Tool.Script:2: attempt to index nil with 'Character'
```

Can someone please tell me how I can animate this tool?  I'm not sure if its because how its built because all the scripts iv'e seen on yt don't work for me either with the same error.

Comment: I moved it out from under Return script by the way but still the same error thats all.  Help Please!

Comment: Heyo, please don't post pictures of your code. Instead, please edit your question and copy and paste your code into the question. That will allow us to easily work with your code and test it for ourselves. The same goes for your error message.

Comment: Thanks, sorry I'm new to this site.

Answer (score 1):

You never defined what "character" is. You are basically telling it to find the child of nothing.

```
local tool = script.Parent
local player = tool.script.Parent.Parent
local character = player.Character
--Rest of Code
```